# Как убрать тряску от анимации?

Tags: html, css, анимация

столкнулся с проблемой, когда вместе с анимированными элементами возникает тряска соседних элементов. Как с ней бороться?
Видео: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rfa_ZfobwqIONk_e8a4unPfRVwBF2s5h/view?usp=sharing

HTML:

```
  <div class="info-container">
        <p class="info-container__brackets_gradient animated-item">{&nbsp;}</p> 
        <p class="info-container__grid_gradient animated-item">#</p>
        <h1 class="info-container__profile-name">Трясущийся текст</h1>
        <p class="info-container__text">Трясущийся текст</p>
        <button  class="info-container__button_red">Трясущаяся кнопка</button>
        <p class="info-container__div_gradient animated-item">&lt;div&gt;</p>
        <p class="info-container__div2_gradient animated-item">&lt;div&gt;</p>
        <p class="info-container__slash_gradient animated-item">&lt;/&gt;</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .animated-item {
    animation-duration: 5s;
    z-index: 999; 

    }

    @keyframes tag-1 {
    0% {
        top: 80%;
        left: 70%;
        font-size: 0;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes tag-2 {
    0% {
        top: 80%;
        left: 70%;
        font-size: 0;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes tag-3 {
    0% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 80%;
        font-size: 0;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes tag-4 {
    0% {
        top: 55%;
        left: 17%;
        font-size: 0;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes tag-5 {
    0% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes tag-6 {
    0% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

    .info-container {
    padding-bottom: 74px;
    margin-left: 366px;
}

.info-container__div_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f26522 0%, #fa0891 99%, #fa0891 100%);
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transform: translate(409px, -390px) rotate(-14deg);
    animation-name: tag-1;
}

.info-container__div2_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f26522 0%, #fa0891 99%, #fa0891 100%);
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 38px;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transform: translate(587px, -112px) rotate(22deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    animation-name: tag-2;
}

.info-container__slash_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f26522 0%, #fa0891 99%, #fa0891 100%);
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transform: translate(-3px, -43px) rotate(-23deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    animation-name: tag-3;
}

.info-container__brackets_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f26522 0%, #fa0891 99%, #fa0891 100%);
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transform: translate(-229px, 77px) rotate(28deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    animation-name: tag-4;
}

.info-container__grid_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f26522 0%, #fa0891 99%, #fa0891 100%);
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transform: translate(-118px, 195px) rotate(17deg);
    animation-name: tag-5;
}

    .info-container__profile-name {
    align-self: center;
    color: #1f1f24;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 104.64px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    }

    .info-container__text {
    color: #8993ad;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 487px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

    .info-container__button_red { 
    height: 60px; 
    width: 270px; 
    font-family: 'Roboto'; 
    color: white; 
    background-color: #ff4e2e;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-grow: 0;
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: 44px;
}
```

Comment: Анимируй только transform.

Comment: еще прикол в "тряске" может быть из-за падингов

Comment: Установите изображение внуть например div  с константной шириной и высотой достаточного размера с запасом в пиксель-два подберёте, что бы при анимации хватило места на смену размера. Что бы не переносило елементы, display:inline-block поставить.